# Add button to a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an update table with a button, but the button is not show in the row.
please help me to add the button to the table.
thanks.

```
                function addRow(){
                     var ref = firebase.database().ref();
                       ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                       numPhotos=snapshot.child("La_Cartelera").child("ok").val();
                     })
                     var realNumPhotos=numPhotos-1;

                     for(var i =1; i<realNumPhotos; i++){
                     var ref = firebase.database().ref();
                       ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                       board=snapshot.child(i).child("Board").val();
                       imageChild=snapshot.child(i).child("Image").val();
                     })
                       console.log(i);
                       console.log(board);
                       rowNum = realNumPhotos-i;

                       var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                       btn.innerHTML = "Confirm";
                       document.body.appendChild(btn);

                   var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                   var row = table.insertRow(0);
                   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                   var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                   cell1.innerHTML =  rowNum
                   cell2.innerHTML =  board
                   cell3.innerHTML =  imageChild
                   cell4.innerHTML =  btn
                 }
               }
```

[image]

Comment: do you want a single update button in the last row or an update button in each row?.. A complete example would be cool, so that people can easily test their solution for your problem.

Comment: I want the button in each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code adds your button now:

```
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Which is just appending it to the end of your body.

An approach could be like how you did your table

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
```

Give the row you want to append to an id and then append it to that.

```
var rowButtons = document.getElementById("rowButtons");
rowButtons.appendChild(btn);
```

if you have multiple rows. Use a class to get **all** rows

```
allRows = document.getElementsByClassName("rowButton");
```

Then loop them all and add button.

```
for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
  allRows[i].appendChild(btn)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this line `document.body.appendChild(btn);`. You are appending the `btn` to the body and not the row

Answer (score 1):

You don't need append confirm buttons to the `body`, this mean, you have an unused line - `document.body.appendChild(btn);` , just remove it.

And, if you want to push a html element to another element, you can use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML =`.

In your case, you want to push a button into a cell (`cell4`), then you have to change `cell4.innerHTML = btn` to `cell4.appendChild(btn)`

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can use templates:

say you have:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then you can use templating like [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) to put the template in the table.

like

```
<script id="table-tempalte" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each}}
<tr>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td><button>Edit Button</button></td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

You can compile this template as HTML and then put it in DOM.

This will help you add elements easily to the DOM and you can reference them by parent element since they will not be present by default while DOM Creation.